# Fast Multitenant Caching - Local Caching in Addition to Distributed Caching. Or are they the same thing?

Tags: redis, distributed-cache

I am working on converting an existing single tenant application to a multitenant one. Distributed caching is new to me. We have an existing primitive local cache system using the .NET cache that generates cloned objects from existing cached ones. I have been looking at utilizing Redis.

**Can Redis cache and invalidate locally in addition to over the wire thus replacing all benefit of the local primitive cache? Or would it potentially be an ideal approach to have a tiered approach utilizing Redis distributed cache if the local one doesn't have the objects we need?**  *I believe the latter would imply requiring expiration notifications to happen against the local caches when data is updated otherwise servers may have out of date inconsistent data*

It seems like a set of local caches with expiration notifications would also qualify as a distributed cache, so I am a bit confused here on how Redis might be configured and if it would be distributed accross the servers serving the requests or live in it's own cluster.

When I say *local* I am implying not having to go over the wire for data.